# How to get the preview monitor work through Livestream API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm using Livestream API to transition a stream from "ready" to "testing". And after successful transition to "testing",
the response returned with `contentDetails` object with `monitorStream.embedHtml`.

But the embedded html with the livemonitor, is displaying "sign in to view this video". My app is already authorized with OAuth 2.0.

Isn't it possible to view the Preview through the embedded html?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, according to this document - [Stage 3: Test](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast#Test), 
you embed a player that shows the monitor stream for your broadcast so that you can test the viewing experience.

Follow the steps:

> 1. Embed a monitor stream player
>
>    Retrieve your broadcast using the [**`liveBroadcasts.list`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) method, and extract the value of the **`contentDetails.streamDetails.monitorStreamEmbedHtml`** property. That value contains the HTML that you need to embed a YouTube player that shows your monitor stream.
> 2. Start your video
>
>    Start transmitting video on your video stream.

Following this should help you preview your livestream for testing. You may also check how you authorize your request since a sign in is being display to view the video.

#### NOTE:

> The monitor stream is a private stream that lets you preview the broadcast video as it would appear to YouTube viewers. Note that you can only test your video broadcast if its [monitor stream is enabled](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#enableMonitorStream).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm able to transition between "ready" to "testing", "testing" to "live", "live" to "complete" without any problem. 

Even got the embedded html for monitor.

According to the document, `if its contentDetails.monitorStream.enableMonitorStream property is set to true.` which confirms that my stream is enabled for monitoring the stream.

If my authorization was not successful, after transitioning to the testing, I wouldn't be able to transition again to "live".

Something going wrong... can't figure it out.

But I can view the monitor just fine from the Youtube UI, after transition

Comment: Followed all the steps again as it noted on the manual, still not able to work the test monitor. Wondering, is it just me or there is a bug.